# IOS: getting values in an array from dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

In my project i have an array which contains multiple dictionaries with some key values each. I want to get the all the value of "Link" key into an `NSMutableArray`. 
the current array which contain dictionary is in the form of:

```
(
                {
            YoutubeVideo =             {
                description = "Cervical Spine Medial Branch Nerve Neurolysis neurosurgical animations";
                link = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/26186155";
                title = "Cervical Spine Medial Branch Nerve Neurolysis neurosurgical animations";
            };
        },
                {
            YoutubeVideo =             {
                description = "What is endoscopic brain surgery";
                link = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/16144037";
                title = "What is endoscopic brain surgery";
            };
        },
                {
            YoutubeVideo =             {
                description = "Cervical Spine Medial Branch Nerve Block Injection pain management";
                link = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/26186167";
                title = "Cervical Spine Medial Branch Nerve Block Injection pain management";
            };
        },
                {
            YoutubeVideo =             {
                description = "Seguiremos - Hospital Sant Joan de D\U00e9u y Macaco";
                link = "https://player.vimeo.com/video/54275902";
                title = "Seguiremos - Hospital Sant Joan de D\U00e9u y Macaco";
            };
        },
                {
            YoutubeVideo =             {
                description = "Basic Shoulder Arthroscopy in Orthopaedics";
                link = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ywBVWIzGxtw";
                title = "Basic Shoulder Arthroscopy in Orthopaedics";
            };
        }
```

i want to get all the values of link into a single array.
Currently the code i use which gives the following output is:

```
-(void)videolisting
{
    NSString *post = @"api_key=bf45c093e542f057c123ae7d6";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://hChe/api/video"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];


    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"str : %@",str);

    NSDictionary *dict6 = [self cleanJsonToObject:responseData];
    //NSLog(@"str : %@",dict6);

    vidnamearray = [dict6 objectForKey:@"video"];
    NSLog(@" Required Dir: %@",vidnamearray);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below solution

```
    NSMutableArray *subArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(NSDictionary *dict in vidnamearray)
    {
        NSDictionary *subDict=[dict valueForKey:@"YoutubeVideo"];
        [subArray addObject:[subDict valueForKey:@"link"]];
    }
```

subArray will get all the values in the link key..!

Hope it helps you.....!

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
yourArr.valueForKeyPath("YoutubeVideo.link")
```

This will give the array containing all links.